# What does OS X use "associated" Apple IDs for?

Tags: security, apple-id, system-settings, accounts

On OS X it is possible to associate Apple IDs with user accounts. [Apple lists](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11389) three consequences of doing so:

1. The Apple IDs can be used to reset the user account
2. The Apple IDs can be used to access the computer for file and screen sharing
3. The Apple IDs can be used share files and screens with other computers

Is this the complete list? Are there other consequences of associating an Apple ID with a user account? I don't do any of these things (I've disabled them where possible) but do use my Apple IDs extensively for other things. Will I loose any functionality other than the three listed above, if I [delete my Apple IDs](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/how-to-avoid-associating-your-apple-id-with-your-macs-account-in-mountain-lion/) from my account?

Comment: You do not trust the knowledge base article on the matter? :)

Comment: @Gerry: You don't understand the question I'm asking. I'm not asking whether the list is correct, I'm asking whether the list is *complete*. You're certainly aware that it is common, even in technical writing, to provide partial lists of consequences of settings or configuration choices. Knowing for sure that there are no other consequences before I advise people to delete their Apple IDs would be very helpful. If you're that confident that the list is complete by all means answer "Yes, that is the complete list, there are no other consequences of deleting your Apple ID" and I'll accept.

Comment: I do understand the question, it just would be a better question if you were asking something more specific, like "will feature X stop working if I disassociate my AppleID from my user account?". Also see the [FAQ] under "What kind of questions should I not ask here?".

Comment: @Gerry: It's quite a specific question: If I make deletion of Apple IDs part of my security policy, will I have users complaining that they've lost some functionality or can I guarantee that nothing of consequence will change for them?

Comment: I understand where the OP is coming from. Apple user docs are written simply, and without depth, and have no real procedure to solve problems, and they above all, do not tell you anything that would make you _less_ dependent. This is a very astute question, I will use this wording in future.

Comment: Plus, this question seeks experience, not just knowledge. How can you be specific when you are dealing with ellipsis?